# PalPal trasaction API send shipping info address "state" null?

Tags: c#, paypal, e-commerce, reporting

I have an E-Commerce site where I implement PayPal as a payment method for checkout. In some cases, payment is made but order didn't process by the site. So I use a backgound service to track the payments and orders. I use **v1/reporting/transactions** API to fetch all the transaction with event code **T0006 (PayPal Checkout APIs)**. API fetches the trasaction successfully but each trasaction when I go to the node **Address** I see PayPal returns null for the object **state** but sometimes it send the state. So my question is how do I get the state of a transaction because state is mandatory to ship order to specified location?

```
var apiContext = PaypalAPIHelper.GetAPIContext();
var transactionslist = PaypalAPIHelper.GetTransactionHistory(apiContext, startDateUtc, endDateUtc);
//transaction detail are not null
if (transactionslist.transaction_details != null)
{
    foreach (var itemTransaction in transactionslist.transaction_details.Where(m => m.transaction_info.transaction_event_code == "T0006").Where(m => m.payer_info.payer_name.given_name != null).OrderByDescending(m => m.transaction_info.transaction_initiation_date))
    {
        var missingOrderObj = new MissingOrder();
        if (itemTransaction.transaction_info.transaction_event_code == "T0006" && itemTransaction.transaction_info.transaction_status == "S")
        {
            try
            {
                string PayPalTransactionStatus = Util.GetPayPalTransactionStatusDescription(itemTransaction.transaction_info.transaction_status);
                var orderData = GetOrderByPaypalTransactionId(itemTransaction.transaction_info.transaction_id, "", itemTransaction.cart_info.item_details.FirstOrDefault().item_code);
                if (orderData == null && itemTransaction.transaction_info.transaction_id != null)
                {
                    //Retrive all items in a single transaction
                    if (itemTransaction.cart_info.item_details != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var productItem in itemTransaction.cart_info.item_details)
                        {
                            var i = new Item();
                            i.ItemAmount = productItem.item_amount == null ? "" : productItem.item_amount.value;
                            i.ItemCode = string.IsNullOrEmpty(productItem.item_code) ? "" : productItem.item_code;
                            i.ItemName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(productItem.item_name) ? "" : productItem.item_name;
                            i.ItemQuantity = string.IsNullOrEmpty(productItem.item_quantity) ? "" : productItem.item_quantity;
                            i.ItemTotalAmount = productItem.total_item_amount == null ? "" : productItem.total_item_amount.value;
                            missingOrderObj.items.Add(i);
                        }
                    }
                    //Populate payer
                    missingOrderObj.payer.PayerEmail = itemTransaction.payer_info.email_address;
                    missingOrderObj.payer.PayerFirstName = itemTransaction.payer_info.payer_name.given_name;
                    missingOrderObj.payer.PayerLastName = itemTransaction.payer_info.payer_name.surname;
                    //Populate shipping
                    missingOrderObj.shipping.City = itemTransaction.shipping_info.address == null ? "" : itemTransaction.shipping_info.address.city;
                    missingOrderObj.shipping.CountryCode = itemTransaction.shipping_info.address == null ? "" : itemTransaction.shipping_info.address.country_code;
                    missingOrderObj.shipping.Line1 = itemTransaction.shipping_info.address == null ? "" : itemTransaction.shipping_info.address.line1;
                    missingOrderObj.shipping.Line2 = itemTransaction.shipping_info.address == null ? "" : itemTransaction.shipping_info.address.line2;
                    missingOrderObj.shipping.PostalCode = itemTransaction.shipping_info.address == null ? "" : itemTransaction.shipping_info.address.postal_code;
                    
                    //Here the state is null
                    missingOrderObj.shipping.State = itemTransaction.shipping_info.address == null ? "" : itemTransaction.shipping_info.address.state;
                    missingOrderObj.shipping.Name = itemTransaction.shipping_info.name;
                    //Populate Transaction
                    missingOrderObj.transaction.FeeAmount = itemTransaction.transaction_info.fee_amount == null ? "" : itemTransaction.transaction_info.fee_amount.value;
                    missingOrderObj.transaction.ShippingAmount = itemTransaction.transaction_info.shipping_amount == null ? "" : itemTransaction.transaction_info.shipping_amount.value;
                    missingOrderObj.transaction.TotalAmount = itemTransaction.transaction_info.transaction_amount == null ? "" : itemTransaction.transaction_info.transaction_amount.value;
                    missingOrderObj.transaction.TransactionId = string.IsNullOrEmpty(itemTransaction.transaction_info.transaction_id) ? "" : itemTransaction.transaction_info.transaction_id;
                    missingOrderObj.transaction.TransactionDate = string.IsNullOrEmpty(itemTransaction.transaction_info.transaction_initiation_date.ToString()) ? DateTime.Now : itemTransaction.transaction_info.transaction_initiation_date;
                    missingOrderObj.transaction.TransactionStatus = string.IsNullOrEmpty(PayPalTransactionStatus) ? "" : PayPalTransactionStatus;
                    payPalTransactionList.Add(missingOrderObj);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Write(ex.Message + ex.InnerException + ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }
    }
    //Sending json to my site for order creation
}
```

I check with some documentation. Someone says that you use GeoCoding API to get the state by passing address line or something, but its beating around the bush. So is there any other method like GetPayment from paypal where I see the state is not null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A correct integration uses the v2/checkout/orders API (or similar) to create and capture payments, and on capture receives an immediate notification of success or failure. Mostly your problems should be solved by moving to such a correct integration, the [standard integration guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/) gives sample code in node.js , and the backend portion can of course be implemented in any language including c#

I strongly recommend focusing your efforts on the above, but if for some reason you also decide you need a separate asynchronous notification of events, the v1/reporting/transactions API is not the correct way to do it. Instead, [integrate webhooks](https://developer.paypal.com/api/rest/webhooks/event-names/). However, webhooks are generally only useful as an add on integration for events that are truly asynchronous, such as later refunds or disputes or payments moving out of a pending state for some reason. With the exception of some alternate payment methods (that could complete on 3rd party sites), normal order captures should not need to rely on separate asynchronous notifications -- neither webhooks, nor the ill-suited polling of v1/reporting/transactions